# How to import .py file in jupyter notebook from AWS S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a jupyter notebook in AWS, I have two files: main.ipynb and utils.py, what I would like to do is to `import utils` in my jupyter notebook file.

Unfortunately I have tried the following solutions and none of them are working:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("/home/jovyan/dir1")
%load utils.py
```

And to directly import after changing the directory

```
import utils
```

my file "utils.py":

```
def hello():
    print("hello")
```

Problem solved:

the solution is to add those :

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file(os.environ['S3_BUCKET'], "dir1/utils.py", "utils.py")

import utils
```

Answer (score 0):

Export python path to the path from where you are trying to import utils.
Run this below command from you file path

```
export $PYTHONPATH=.
```

Comment: where do I write this code ? in my jupyter notebook ?

Comment: You need run that command on terminal.
Can you share some more details of your exact issue ? I just created two files "main.ipynb" and "utils.py"(jus like yours) in my jupyter workspace then i tried to import utils in main.ipynb notebook console and it worked.

Comment: actually it is not exactly on my jupyter notebook, it is on my jupyter notebook on AWS where everything is stored in S3 format. Like if you want to open a csv file you have to do like:     fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)

    with fs.open(os.environ['S3_BUCKET'] + f'{path}/{dataset_name}') as f:
             df = pd.read_table(f, sep=sep)

Comment: So jupyter is deployed on AWS EC2 ? In that case you can run `export $PYTHONPATH=.` command on path where those two files exist on EC2. Have you also stored these py files in S3 ?

Comment: I have tried your solution I have an error: jovyan@a9399f9a2574:~/Churn$ export $PYTHONPATH=.
bash: export: `=.': not a valid identifier
jovyan@a9399f9a2574:~/Churn$ python
Python 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  1 2019, 21:52:21)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> export $PYTHONPATH=.
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    export $PYTHONPATH=.
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I have also tried to add again to the sys.path with : import sys

sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+"/Churn")

for path in sys.path:
    print(path) ; my directory is correctly added to the sys.path but it is not working when I do import utils